# Set the value of a list column in powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

This is for SharePoint 2019 on-premise.

I need to be able to set values and properties to the Documents folder that has custom columns added (via Powershell).

So for Documents List in site foo.bar I have added:

1. Relevant  type=YesNo  and I want to set this to False.
2. Groups  type=choice with the following choice ["A","B","C",D"], set to multichoice

I have no problem creating the columns via powershell but everything i tried when it comes to updating those fields just fails.

So far i have tried a days worth of code examples google searching but the more complete examples are not for SharePoint On-Premise.

the code to create the Lists i found at http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2015/12/how-to-add-column-to-sharepoint-list-using-powershell.html

but the choice field example didnt work nor did other sites like technet. I am missing something and I cannot seem to locate the answer.

Any complete examples of setting values within a SharePoint List using would be great.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: I don't understand, you want to set the value for each item in a list for columns that you have added, or you want to change the type of the columns for the columns that you have added? I ask because (according to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/ms428806(v%3Doffice.15))) `YesNo` isn't a type, but `boolean` is, and the `Choice` type is different from the `MultiChoice` type.

Comment: If using the Documents folder as an example and I add two columns: columnA and columnB. ColumnA I create as a boolean or yesno column. I want to set the default property to No instead of Yes.  ColumnB is a multichoice column, in that column i want to add the following data: item1,item2,item3 and change its Display choice to CheckBoxes (allow multiple selections).

Comment: The code you link to seems well enough and it emits errors when adding fields to the list. Do you get any of those? Are you using the correct [SPFieldType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldtype?view=sharepoint-server) s? Otherwise, show us the code you now have so we can see if maybe you've forgotten something. Do that by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55857162/edit) your question and format the code.